# Change selected class to first instead of last date

Tags: php

I want my first date to be the selected one but as it is now the last one is the selected one, i've managed to get the years in the right order but the only problem im having now is getting the selected class on the first date instead of the ast one.

```
<div class="timeline">
<?php
$tl = unserialize($properties['timeline']);
$years = array();
foreach($tl as $t)
{
    $e=explode("-", $t['date']);
    $years[$e[2]][strtotime($t['date'])]=$t;
}
ksort($years);
?>

<div class="events-wrapper">
    <div class="events">
        <ol>
            <?php
            $i=1;
            foreach($years as $y=>$t)
            {
                echo '<li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/'.$y.'"'.($i==count($years)?' class="selected"':' class="older-event"').'>'.$y.'</a></li>';
                $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </ol>

        <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div> <!-- .events -->
</div> <!-- .events-wrapper -->
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: change `($i==count($years)` to `($i == 1)`

Comment: haha i feel so stupid now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your condition inside the foreach loop `($i==count($years)` to `($i == 1)`.

```
foreach($years as $y=>$t){
    echo '<li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/'.$y.'"'.($i==1)?' class="selected"':' class="older-event"').'>'.$y.'</a></li>';
    $i++;
}
```